# Dependence relations in the group $a^4=b^4=(ab)^{15}=1$

Tags: group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

There are two generators: $a$ and $b$. It is known that $a^4 = b^4 = (ab)^{15} = (ab^2)^6 = (ab^3)^9 = 1$.

Is it possible and how to express relations $(ab^2)^6 = (ab^3)^9 = 1$ through relations $a^4 = b^4 = (ab)^{15} = 1$?

PS In this case, the generators are rotations of adjacent faces of the 2x2 Rubik’s Cube. However, I would like to know the answer without considering this information.

Comment: Take a group with only the first three relations, and quotient out by the normal subgroup generated by $ab$. You get a cyclic group of order $4$, and even there we don't have $$(ab^2)^6=1$$

Comment: If we additionally assume $a^2=b^2=1$, then the question becomes whether $(ab)^3=1$ is provable from $a^2=b^2=(ab)^{15}=1$.  This describes the dihedral group of symmetries of a $15$-gon, where $ab$ is a rotation of $2\pi/15$.  In this group, $(ab)^3$ is a rotation of $2\pi/5$, not the identity map.